# why is the error: Pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int* a = new int;
    *a = 5;

    int* b = new int;
    *b = 6;

    int* temp = a;
    delete(a);
    a = b;
    b = temp;

    cout << *temp << endl;
    delete (temp); // error



    return 0;
}
```

error : malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffdff400630: pointer being freed was not allocated.
But if I do not `delete(a)`, it works.

Comment: You've stored the value of `a` in `temp`, released `a`, retrieved the value from `temp` (which is now invalid since `a` has been released) and used it.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.

Comment: Pointers is a dangerous game to play

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
int* temp = a;
```

both `a` and `temp` point to the same memory that was allocated in the line

```
int* a = new int;
```

When you use

```
delete(a);
```

that memory was deallocated. At that time, both `temp` and `a` are dangling pointers.

By using

```
a = b;
b = temp;
```

you changed `a` to point to a valid memory but now both `b` and `temp` are dangling pointers.

Use of `temp` in

```
cout << *temp << endl;
delete (temp); // error
```

is not correct. Both of them are cause for undefined behavior. With undefined behavior, it is pointless to try to make sense of what happens -- anything can happen.

> But if I do not `delete(a)`, it works.

That makes sense. Without that call, all the pointers continue to be valid till the end of the function.

You should add code to delete both the pointers before the end of the function though. But then you have to keep track of which pointers are valid to be used in the calls to `delete`.

You can print their values to figure that out.

```
std::cout << "a: " << (void*)a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b: " << (void*)b << std::endl;
std::cout << "temp: " << (void*)temp << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
int* temp = a;
```

You make copy of the pointer, So `a` and `temp` points to same thing,
Then in

```
delete a;
```

You delete `a` so `temp`  becomes a dangling pointer, de-referencing it causes undefined behavior.

Ideally you should do

```
temp = null;
```

just after the `delete` or for the better use shared pointer that ships with modern CPP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

auto main() -> int
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(5);

    std::cout << "ptr value is " << *ptr << std::endl;

    auto ptr1 = ptr; // Reference counted copy

    std::cout << "ptr value is " << *ptr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total reference count :" << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;
    ptr.reset(); // Resetting  ptr, thus reference count drops to 1
    std::cout << "Total reference count :" << ptr1.use_count() << std::endl;;

    return 0;
}
```